# Ownership: differences between tuples and arrays in Rust

Tags: rust

I am starting to learn Rust, and while experimenting, I have found a difference in how ownership is applied to tuples and arrays I do not understand. Basically, the following code shows the difference:

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]

struct Inner {
    in_a: u8,
    in_b: u8
}
struct Outer1 {
    a: [Inner; 2]
}

struct Outer2 {
    a: (Inner, Inner)
}

fn test_ownership(num: &mut u8, inner: &Inner) {
}

fn main() {
    let mut out1 = Outer1 {
        a: [Inner {in_a: 1, in_b: 2}, Inner {in_a: 3, in_b: 4}]
    };
    let mut out2 = Outer2 {
        a: (Inner {in_a: 1, in_b: 2}, Inner {in_a: 3, in_b: 4})
    };

    // This fails to compile
    test_ownership(&mut out1.a[0].in_a, &out1.a[1]);
    // But this works!
    test_ownership(&mut out2.a.0.in_a, &out2.a.1);
}
```

The first invocation of `test_ownership()` does not compile, as expected Rust emits an error complaining about taking both a mutable and immutable reference to `out1.a[_]`.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `out1.a[_]` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:41
   |
27 |     test_ownership(&mut out1.a[0].in_a, &out1.a[1]);
   |     -------------- -------------------  ^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |     |              |
   |     |              mutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow later used by call
```

But the thing I do not understand, is why the second invocation of `test_ownership()` does not make the borrow checker go nuts? It seems as if arrays are considered as a whole independently of the indexes being accessed, but tuples allow multiple mutable references to their different indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuples are like anonymous structs, and accessing an element in a tuple behaves like accessing a **struct field**.

Structs can be partially borrowed (and also partially moved), so `&mut out2.a.0.in_a` borrows only the first field of the tuple.

The same does not apply to indexing. The indexing operator can be overloaded by implementing [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ops/trait.IndexMut.html), so `&mut out1.a[0].in_a` is equivalent to `&mut out1.a.index_mut(0).in_a`. While `a.0` just accesses a field, `a[0]` calls a function! Functions can't partially borrow something, so the indexing operator must borrow the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed an interesting case. For the second case it works because compiler understands that different part of the structure is borrowed ([there's a section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) in nomicon for that). For the first case compiler is, unfortunately is not that smart (indexing is generally performed by a runtime calculated value), so you need to destruct it manually:

```rust
let [mut x, y] = out1.a;
test_ownership(&mut x.in_a, &y);
```

Comment: Interesting. Destructuring the array as you wrote, requires moving `out1.a`,  so if later I wanted to use it, that would not work, right? Could it be possible doing something similar using references? I suspect it might not be possible without going the unsafe route.

Comment: @doragasu You can use [`split_first_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first_mut) or another one of the split functions to do this safely on references on arrays.

Comment: As for the array case, I'd rather prefer bind-by-ref: `let [ref mut x, ref y] = out1.a;`, because splitting might be tedious for array sizes >2.

Comment: @Kitsu: Tested as you wrote with the `ref` keyword, and it works nice and easy. Got to give the `split_first_mut` a try also.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the tuple case and the indexing case is what is being used to perform the indexing. In the tuple case we are using syntax sugar over what is effectively an identifier into a struct. As it is an identifier, which field is accessed must be static. As such there is a simple set of rules the borrow checker can follow to determine lifetimes, which follows the same rules used for struct fields.

In the case of an indexing, this is in stable rust an inherently dynamic operation. The index is not an identifier, but an expression. Since the stable typesystem does not yet have a concept of constant expressions or type level values, the borrow checker always treats the index as if it dynamic, even in trivial cases such as yours which are are clearly static. Since they are dynamic, it can't prove non-equality of the indexes, so the borrow conflicts.